# «Вот так, так(,) и ещё раз так, и ещё много-много так!»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и

> Сейчас покажу, как делать: вот так, так(,) и ещё раз так, и ещё много-много так!

Нужна ли запятая после второго «так»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая нужна. Думаю, к данному случаю подходит следующее правило:

> 6. Если однородных членов предложения более двух, а союз повторяется перед каждым из них, кроме первого, то **запятая** ставится между всеми однородными членами: *Листья в поле **пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят; Лён, и полотна, и пряжу** несут; А вокруг были **дым, и бой, и смерть*** (М. Г.); *Отрывистый и ломаный звук **метался, и прыгал, и бежал** куда-то в сторону от других* (Андр.); *Иные хозяева вырастили уже **вишни, или сирень, или жасмин*** (Ф).

Источник: [Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#) (справочник Розенталя).